# hydra - creating policy using curl fails with invalid scope

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

I have successfully configured ory/hydra OAUTH server and it seems to be working well.  However, I am trying to create a policy using "curl" instead of the provided CLI and am running into an error:

```
{"error":{"code":500,"message":"A validator returned an error: The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed"}}
```

The error, unfortunately, is not detailed enough to allow me to determine a root cause.

Here is the request that I am issuing via curl:

```
curl -k -X POST -H Authorization: bearer aValidBearerToken \
    -d {"id":"policy-001", "description":"some description", "subjects":["aValidClient"], "actions":["read"], "effect":"allow", "resources":["aResource"] } \
    https://localhost:4444/policies
```

Also, I have verified that I have a valid bearer token.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue -- as the error message stated, I have an invalid scope, which could only be caused by the bearer token being generated with an invalid scope.  Sure enough, I had created the bearer token with the scope

```
"hydra.clients"
```

and it should have been:

```
"hydra hydra.clients"
```

The added "hydra" allowed the permission to create policies which was not available with the previously defined scope "hydra.clients" (which only allowed clients to be created)